# Change the Color of Intellisense Suggestion area Font Color in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to change the color of Intellisense Suggestions Font in Visual Studio Code (VS Code)
[image]

I looked up here in, [Visual Studio Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) , I see many options but didn't really found a solution. Also I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Not directly the answer, but what about picking one the [existing theme in the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Themes&sortBy=Installs)? I personally use [Bearder theme collection](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BeardedBear.beardedtheme) (Monokai stone)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `editorSuggestWidget.*` in the settings JSON (with the `editorSuggestWidget.foreground` and `editorSuggestWidget.selectedForeground` being the specific settings you are after to change the font colors).  You can specify these settings on a per-theme basis (my example is for `[Default Dark+]`:

[image: image of the editorSuggestWidget setting]

```json
{
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
      "editorSuggestWidget.background": "#ff0000",
      "editorSuggestWidget.foreground": "#1411e7",
      "editorSuggestWidget.selectedBackground": "#23a816",
      "editorSuggestWidget.highlightForeground": "#18b6c2",
      "editorSuggestWidget.focusHighlightForeground": "#d10ab0"
    }
}
```